# emacs smartscan change key bindings

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I have installed smartscan in emacs 24 but the default key binding took over M-n and M-p keys which I need when using emacs shell to go to previous next item in command history.

;; adds VIM like super star * kind of search to emacs with M-n, M-p keys
(global-smartscan-mode t) ;; Turn on Smart Scan globally

How can I use configure smartscan to use a different key binding and leave M-n, M-p bindings as they were?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `smartscan-map`.

```
(with-eval-after-load "smartscan"
  (define-key smartscan-map (kbd "C-c s M-n") 'smartscan-symbol-go-forward)
  (define-key smartscan-map (kbd "C-c s M-p") 'smartscan-symbol-go-backward)
  (define-key smartscan-map (kbd "C-c s M-'") 'smartscan-symbol-replace))
```

---

Alternatively, you can only enable `smartscan-mode` in `prog-mode` (which is probably the only modes it's useful in).  This is what I do.  It doesn't seem to affect `eshell` or `shell`, but I only did a quick test as I don't normally use those.

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'smartscan-mode)
```